# Why the import "from tensorflow.train import Feature" doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

That's probably totally noob question which has something to do with python module importing, but I can't understand why the following is valid:

```
> import tensorflow as tf
> f = tf.train.Feature()

> from tensorflow import train
> f = train.Feature()
```

But the following statement causes an error:

```
> from tensorflow.train import Feature
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.train'
```

Can please somebody explain me why it doesn't work this way? My goal is to use more short notation in the code like this:

```
> example = Example(
    features=Features(feature={
        'x1': Feature(float_list=FloatList(value=feature_x1.ravel())),
        'x2': Feature(float_list=FloatList(value=feature_x2.ravel())),
        'y': Feature(int64_list=Int64List(value=label))
    })
)
```

tensorflow version is 1.7.0

Comment: I don't know why this error is being thrown (and I don't want to go into the details), but I know a "workaround" to achieve what you want. You can import `train` as in one of your examples, that is, `from tensorflow import train`, then you do `Feature = train.Feature` (Note that I am assigning a class object to a variable called `Feature`, i.e. creating an alias). After that, you can just use `Feature(...)` without prefixing it with `train` (or any other prefixes).

Comment: Yes, that workaround will work. But if I want to do the same with 3-6 more classes (FloatList, Int64List, BytesList, Example, etc) code becomes a little bit more messy - have to repeat the same procedure for each class.

Comment: There is an open issue on this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33289

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

Replace

```
from tensorflow.train import Feature
```

with

```
from tensorflow.core.example.feature_pb2 import Feature
```

### Explanation

#### Remarks about TensorFlow's Aliases

In general, you have to remember that, for example:

```
from tensorflow import train
```

is actually an alias for

```
from tensorflow.python.training import training
```

You can easily check the real module name by printing the module. For the current example you will get:

```
from tensorflow import train
print (train)
<module 'tensorflow.python.training.training' from ....
```

#### Your Problem

In Tensorflow 1.7, you can't use `from tensorflow.train import Feature`, because the `from` clause needs an actual module name (and not an alias). Given `train` is an alias, you will get an `ImportError`.

By doing

```
from tensorflow import train
print (train.Feature)
<class 'tensorflow.core.example.feature_pb2.Feature'>
```

you'll get the complete path of `train`. Now, you can use the import path as shown above in the solution above.

#### Note

In TensorFlow 1.9.0, `from tensorflow.train import Feature` will work, because `tensorflow.train` is an actual *package*, which you can therefore import. (This is what I see in my installed Tensorflow 1.9.0, as well as in the documentation, but not in the Github repository. It must be generated somewhere.)

#### Info about the path of the modules

You can find the complete module path in the docs. Every module has a *"Defined in"* section. See image below (taken from [Module: tf.train](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.7/api_docs/python/tf/train)):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against importing `Feature` (or any other object) from the non-public API, which is inconvenient (you have to figure out where `Feature` is actually defined), verbose, and subject to change in future versions.

I would suggest as an alternative to simply define

```
import tensorflow as tf
Feature = tf.train.Feature
```

Comment: Although this is a pain, this seems to the official workaround (for now). As noted here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33289